# Dagger 2 scope issue, define child fragment module. result: binding is not resolved for interface

Tags: android, dagger-2

I want to use Dagger to compose a module for AFragment with child fragments (X...Z)FragModule.

Starting out from the ActivityBindingModule, I define the an example activity's dependent modules

```
/* ActivityBindingModule.java */
@Module
public abstract class ActivityBindingModule{
    @NonNull
    @ActivityScoped
    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = {
            AFragModule.class,
            BFragModule.class
            // ... fragment modules
    })
    abstract MainActivity mainActivity();
}
```

In AFragModule, I define its child fragment dependent modules.

```
/* AFragModule.java */
@Module
public abstract class AFragModule{
    @NonNull
    @FragmentScoped
    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = {
            XFragModule.class,
            YFragModule.class
            // ... child fragment modules
    })
    abstract AFragment providesFragment();
}
```

In (X...Z)FragModule, I defined its dependent objects' provider methods.

```
/* XFragModule.java */
@Module
public abstract class XFragModule{
    @FragmentScoped
    @ContributesAndroidInjector
    abstract XFragment providesFragment();

    @ActivityScoped
    @Binds
    abstract XContract.Presenter providesPresenter(XPresenter presenter);
}
```

*I want the (X...Z)FragModule modules to be scoped within the AFragModule. And (X...Z)FragModules' presenters alive within the same scope for inter-presenter communication.*

The XPresenter implementation itself uses constructor injector, with @Singleton parameters (eg. datasources)

I get the following error with the above scopes:

```
Cause: binding is not resolved for XContract.Presenter: ProvisionBinding{contributionType=UNIQUE, key=XContract.Presenter, bindingElement=Optional[providesPresenter(XPresenter)], contributingModule=Optional[XFragModule], kind=DELEGATE, nullableType=Optional.empty, wrappedMapKeyAnnotation=Optional.empty, provisionDependencies=[DependencyRequest{kind=INSTANCE, key=XPresenter, requestElement=Optional[presenter], isNullable=false}], injectionSites=[], unresolved=Optional.empty, scope=Optional[@ActivityScoped]}
```

**EDIT:**
I want to check my understanding of scope as well:
I "think" I understand the following

@Singleton > @ActivityScope > @FragmentScope

1. Scopes can't depend on the same or smaller scope
   ex. @ActivityScope can't depend on @ActivityScope or @FragmentScope
2. Scopes can depend on any bigger scope. 
   ex. @FragmentScope can depend on @Singleton, @ActivityScope marked methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your specific case, it looks like Dagger can't find the binding for XPresenter; you have a statement that `@Binds XContract.Presenter` to `XPresenter`, but based on your casual mention of "The XPresenter implementation itself" it looks like you might be missing a statement like:

```
@Binds
abstract XPresenter providesXPresenter(XPresenterImpl presenterImpl);
```

Scopes *can* depend on the same scope: Items in @ActivityScope can depend on @ActivityScope but not @FragmentScope. If you try to depend on a @FragmentScope object from @ActivityScope (a "scope-widening injection"), Dagger will prevent it and describe the components where you can find that injection.

However, you also will likely run into the trouble that a @FragmentScope component  cannot contain other @FragmentScope components, which is a problem given that @ContributesAndroidInjector necessarily creates a new subcomponent that takes the scope and modules listed on the method. You'll need to adjust your choice of scope annotations, such as **creating and using @ParentFragmentScope and @ChildFragmentScope**. This is also important because your @ChildFragmentScope Fragment *XFragment* can inject objects that share the lifecycle of XFragment's subcomponent instance, AFragment's subcomponent instance, MainActivity's subcomponent instance, or your root @Singleton component.

Of course, you'll probably want to name them according to your use case, like @FullScreenFragmentScope or @TabFragmentScope or @OptionalFlowFragmentScope; you can also choose the outer scope to keep @FragmentScope and the inner scope to be @SubFragmentScope or so forth, which might be particularly useful if you have reusable modules that already use @FragmentScope. The point is precisely that a reusable module that uses @FragmentScope is not going to be clear about whether it is tracking AFragment's lifecycle or XFragment's lifecycle, so you're going to need to be clearer about that.